How do you get the list of files under the NTFS special $Extend folder?
I'd like to get the list the contents of the $Extend folder on NTFS drives.  I am sure I've done it in the past but now I get nothing but Access Denied using FindFirstFile, even with the SE_BACKUP_NAME privilege and running as Administrator.
How do you get the list of files under that folder using C++?
Update: I also find I can't even do this:
 CreateFile(_T("C:\\$MFT"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

I also tried $MFT::$DATA, same Access Denied (5) issue.   If you read the MS documentation here, it mentions FSCTL_MOVE_FILE and all the special files that are supported, so you should be able to open them.
TIA!!

When you get an "Access Denied" error, it means that you do not have the correct permissions to access the folder. I suggest you could check whether you have the correct permissions. If the permissions are correct and you've also got this error, you need to determine if the file has been encrypted.

GENERIC_READ remove this. pass 0 here. this must be ok, CreateFileW(L"C:\\$MFT", 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

@RbMm Thank You!! I then messed around with different values, it will also work with FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, but BackupRead still can't read anything (access denied) (just used it as an experiment).   Do you happen to know the answer to the other part of being able to query the files under the $Extend directory?

this is special system files, probably it possible open only from kernel mode (in system process exist opened handles to this files (inside $Extend ). possible enumerate files with special ntfs ioctls and parse ntfs data.
